# Python script: Access data from databases

Tags: python, oracle-dbms

I need to access data that is inside an Oracle database using a Python script. It's a Unix server running oracle 10g. I don't have much access to the database server.

It works fine on model builder when the connection is open and I add my data, but exporting it to Python means all the connection properties are gone (they are just "TABLE NAME" etc.)

Basically the script grabs this information based on a query, let's say `"SELECT id WHERE Status = 0"`, and it writes it to a new table in a filegeodatabase. I need to do it through python as I am processing it further, but that's not my issue.

I just can't get it to connect. I've tried to use pyodbc plugin using the syntax below:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=rtsprod;DATABASE=DBNAME;UID=USERID;PWD=PASSWORD')
```

Now I know it's an Oracle database but can't find any documents on how exactly to connect using the pyodbc plugin. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is more of a StackOverflow question, where it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586361/how-do-i-connect-to-oracle-10-from-pyodbc see also related tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyodbc+oracle

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of built-in options for connecting to Oracle and other DBMS's without using 3rd-party Python modules (not that you couldn't or shouldn't just that there are reasonable alternatives):

- **SDE Connection Files:** If your table is located on an SDE geodatabase, you can use these just as you would any other workspace from arcpy. E.g. `arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\mySDEConnection.sde"`

  - The "Database Connections" shortcut normally points to [%APPDATA%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppData#System_path_variables)\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog; you could also copy these files to another location if required.
  - You can create SDE connection files in ArcCatalog or with the [Create ArcSDE Connection File (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000pt000000) tool.
  - If your table is not located on an SDE geodatabase, but your database administrator is willing to create a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm), you could access the non-SDE Oracle database from an SDE connection file through the DB link using a query with the [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000057000000) command in arcpy.
- **[OLE DB Connection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006m0000006p000000.htm) Files:** Create an OLE DB Connection in ArcCatalog and use it as you would any other workspace from arcpy. E.g. `arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\myOracleDB.odc"`

  - There is currently no geoprocessing tool to let you create OLE DB Connection files, so this must be done beforehand in ArcCatalog.
- **The [Make Query Table (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006r000000) tool:**

  > This tool applies an SQL query to a database and the results are represented in a layer or table view. The query can be used to join several tables or return a subset of columns or rows from the original data in the database.
  >
  > This tool accepts data from an ArcSDE geodatabase, a file geodatabase, a personal geodatabase, or an OLE DB connection.
- **The [Data Interoperability Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004m00000003000000.htm):** This is an integrated version of [FME](http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/) (Feature Manipulation Engine) by Safe Software. See licensing and other info [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/index.html). There are at least a couple of ways you could use this to access your Oracle table.

  1. You could create an [interoperability connection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Interoperability_connections/004m0000001w000000/) to your Oracle database through the ODBC reader (which has direct-read support; see [this list](http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/data-interop-formats.pdf) for supported formats and whether they are direct-read, import or export -- importantly, Oracle Non-Spatial does **not** appear to be direct-read) and use it like any other workspace.
  2. You could use the [Quick Import (Data Interoperability)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001600000005000000.htm) tool to copy the Oracle table to a temporary "staging" file or personal geodatabase.
  3. Depending on how fancy you want to get, you could create a simple [Spatial ETL tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Spatial_ETL_tools/004m0000000m000000/) that just reads and outputs the table, or you could do your entire workflow in it. You could then call this tool from ModelBuilder or Python.
  4. You could create a [custom format](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Custom_formats/004m00000020000000/) that does everything the spatial ETL tool does, but lets you use the result as an interoperability connection or Quick Import format.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, my final connection string was (after a bit more digging):

Theres a print message there to test it works.

```
import cx_Oracle, os, sys

def db_connect():
    # Build a DSN (can be subsitited for a TNS name)
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("ServerName", 1521, "DatabaseName")
    db = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", dsn)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor

def db_lookup(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT SERVICEID FROM SERVICE WHERE STATUS = 0")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row
    return row

cursor = db_connect()
#db_connect()
db_lookup(cursor)
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) - Documentation [here](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html) on making the connection.

> cx_Oracle.connect([user, password, dsn, mode, handle, pool, threaded, twophase, events, cclass, purity, newpassword])
>     
>  **Constructor** for creating a connection to the database. Return a Connection object (Connection Object). All arguments are optional and can be specified as keyword parameters.